# Older or younger than 3 months old?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, double-negation

The below is an excerpt of a document requirement for a UK visa:

> *a bank statement dated no more than three months earlier than the date of application* showing transactions relating to [...]

We're having trouble to agree whether this means older than 3 months or the exact opposite.

What exactly does this mean?

Older than 3 months old? Or the opposite?

Comment: Take the date of application, subtract three months and find a statement between those two dates. So the statement must be less than three months old at the date of application.

Comment: ...no more than three months earlier than.... ???

Comment: A bank statement of three months immediately preceding the date of application...

Comment: What is confusing you? Is it the "no more than three months" or the "earlier"? If it's the combination try thinking about the parts of the requirement then put those thoughts together.

Comment: @BoldBen, thanks. Looking at the separate parts help me a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @BoldBen suggestion, I divided this into parts:

```
|
| earlier than 3 months before
| more than 3 months earlier
------- 3 months before date of application, 3 months earlier
|
| earlier
| no more than 3 months earlier
------- date of application
| after date of application
|
| future
```

Lines are from past to future.

The 2 key dates:

- date of application
- exactly 3 months before date application

Then I placed expressions that I knew I understood in the timeline until I was able to get to an expression matching the original text.

Comment: Glad to help, breaking big problems into smaller parts often helps.

Comment: Think carefully about the context.  You are being asked for evidence, probably that you are who you say you are, have the financial you say you have and things like that.  So the evidence you provide must be as recent as possible.  To demand a statement for the day on which you apply would be much more up-to-date than three months but quite unreasonable, since bank statements are monthly.  Three months or less seems a fair compromise.

Comment: Thanks, @Tuffy.